# how can a client receive more than one broadcast messages when there is more than one server broadcasting?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, broadcastreceiver, inter-process-communicat

I am using system.Net.Socket to send and receive message from server to client.but am facing problem when multiple server broadcasting message then receiver program is being closed suddenly.

My server code for broadcasting is as follows..

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Broadcst
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint iep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9050);
        IPEndPoint iep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), 9050);

        string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hostname);

        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
        sock.SendTo(data, iep1);
        sock.SendTo(data, iep2);
        sock.Close();
    }
}
```

My Receiver Code is as follows for the client...

```
  using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;

    public class RecvBroadcst
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

While(true){
  IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            sock.Bind(iep);
            EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
            string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                                  stringData, ep.ToString());

            data = new byte[1024];
            recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
            stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                                  stringData, ep.ToString());

}
            sock.Close();
        }
    }
```

So how can a client receive more than one broadcast messages when there is more than one server broadcasting?

when i send message again from server its throwing error like "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Comment: Your receiver program 'exits suddenly' as soon as it has received one message, because that's the way you wrote it. If you want it to receive more than one message, adjust the code accordingly. What's the question here?

Comment: i had put that code in while true but when sending next message from server its being close with ought having any message.see my updated question

Comment: The program is not just being "closed". It fails due to an unhandled exception. It is important to interpret that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had Solved the issue with the change in my above code with following in receiver side.i was just binding socket every time so i am just now binding it once and iterate only incoming data every time from the specified port.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class RecvBroadcst
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
     //  int port_no=Convert.ToInt32(sock.RemoteEndPoint);


         int portnumber = 9050;

            sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,portnumber);
            sock.Bind(iep);
            EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");
          // int port_no = Convert.ToInt32(sock.RemoteEndPoint);
            while (true)
            {

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
                string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                                      stringData, ep.ToString());

                //data = new byte[1024];
                //recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
                //stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                //Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                //                      stringData, ep.ToString());

                data = null;
            }
            //portnumber--;


        sock.Close();
    }
}
```

I just got succeeded..thanks for the response.that helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Bind` on the same Socket instance with the same parameters multiple times (one per iteration). You are supposed to call `Bind` once.